# How Can I Enable Developer or Live mode in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have developed a project in spring boot. Now I want to deploy it to a test and live server. I want to configure the project in such a way that if it is in testing mode my sandbox will work. And if it is in live mode my live credentials will work. Is there anything to add in my application.properties file?

Application.properties file:

```
server.port=

spring.datasource.url= sdfasdf
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= 
# spring.datasource.password= 
# spring.datasource.url= 
# spring.datasource.username= 
# spring.datasource.password= 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Application Specific


server.ssl.enabled=false
server.maxHttpHeaderSize = 

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb:
spring.data.mongodb.database=
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring Profiles will solve your problem, i.e; 1.Sandbox and
2.Live

There are two ways to do that which you can see below

1. Create env specific properties file, i.e application-{env}.properties.
   For your case it should be application-sandbox.properties and application-live.properties and in this way, you can provide the separate config for both environments and you can still use application.properties for common configuration like applicationName, etc.
2. You can use the same properties file (application.properties) like this below

   ```
   spring.profile=sandbox        
   #live configurations
   ---
   spring.profile=live
   #live configurations
   ```

Note: One thing to remember is while deploying your jar into any server, specify env name by using property
-Dspring.profiles.active=sandbox(or live)

Comment: Thanks. I have a controller where I have code written both for sandbox and live. I want to dynamically handle these codes. For example if the properties file has only sandbox then my sandbox credentials will work and vice versa. Do I need to retrive the data from application.properties and use that data to dynamically handle the code? 

another thing: Do I need to define both in application.properties if I need only sandbox or only live?

Comment: 1. You need to retreive the data from application-{env}.properties for dynamically handling the code. But remember one thing, when you specify any profile at runtime, it will load all the properties from that specific profile and will not choose another profile.
2. Do I need to define both in application.properties if I need only sandbox or only live? A:- No, you can define only required application-{env}.properties and not all if not required